Can't read value of POST
I can't get the values from a simple form. It has 2 files:  APP.js and FORM.ejs. I am trying to receive the values from the form.
APP.js:
const http = require('http');
const express = require("express");
const S1_APP = express();
const ejs = require("ejs"); 
const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 
S1_APP.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
S1_APP.set('view engine', 'ejs');//template engine

S1_APP.get("", function (req, res) {
    res.render('FORM.ejs');  
});

S1_APP.post("/",function(req, res) {

// here I need to read the value (myvalue 1 or 2) 
// that is send via the form in FORM.ejs
// I have tried req.body, that is empty
// I have tried req.value, that is undefined

});
S1_APP.listen(8080, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Server listening on PORT 8080");
});

FORM.ejs:
<html lang="en" >
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <button type="submit" value="myvalue1"  >POST 1</button>
        <button type="submit" value="myvalue2"  >POST 2</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


The submit buttons need a name. The name  becomes the property name in req.body.

E.g. name="submit", then you can get the value with req.body.submit

You need to add name attribute to form control/element:
    <button name="control1" type="submit" value="myvalue1"  >POST 1</button>
    <button name="control2" type="submit" value="myvalue2"  >POST 2</button>

see:

name
Name of the element. For example used by the server to identify the
fields in form submits.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes


wow, so simple. thanks Barmar and Traynor!

I like to add: the name of the different buttons can be the same, so its not needed to name them control1 and control2. That makes it more simple on the server side. Then req.body.submit gives value1 and value2, depending on which button was pressed.

@raymondvanophoven , if this answer is what you're looking for, you should accept it.
